# C++ how to call method in derived class from base class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

What I want to do is for `Execute()` to run and completes it calls the `Base::Done()` then calls the `Derived::Done()`. I'm doing this because `Base` class `Execute` will do something and when its done call the `Derived::Done()`. I hope I'm explaining it correctly.  Kind of like a listener that is called when a task completed. I'm kinda stuck on how the `Base` class will call the `Derived` class.

```
class Base
{
  virtual void Done(int code){};
  void Execute();
}

void Base::Execute()
{
}


class Derived : Base
{
  void Done(int code);
  void Run();
}

Derived::Done(int code)
{
}

void Derived::Run()
{
    Execute();
}
```

Comment: Although this can be done, you're probably looking for the template method pattern (google).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a template method:

```
class Base
{
 public:
  void Execute()
  {
    BaseDone(42);
    DoDone(42);
  }
 private:
  void BaseDone(int code){};
  virtual void DoDone(int) = 0;
};

class Derived : Base
{
 public:
  void Run() { Execute(); }
 private:
  void DoDone(int code) { .... }
};
```

Here, `Base` controls how its own and derived methods are used in `Execute()`, and the derived types only have to implement one component of that implementation via a private virtual method `DoDone()`.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have a better understanding of it now

Answer (score 4):

The base class method can call the derived method quite simply:

```
void Base::Execute()
{
    Done(42);
}
```

To have the base class Done() called before the derived class, you can either call it as the first statement in the derived class method, or use the non-virtual idiom.

Here's an example of calling it at the top of the derived class method. This relies on the derived class to get it right.

```
void Derived::Done(int code)
{
    Base::Done(code);
}
```

Here's an example of using the non-virtual idiom:

```
class Base
{
    void Done(int code){
        // Do whatever
        DoneImpl(); // Do derived work.
    }
    virtual void DoneImpl() { };
    ...
 };

 class Derived {
     virtual void DoneImpl() { 
         // Do derived class work.
     };
     ...
 };
```

Comment: I tried this example but I keep getting a error
no matching function for call to Base::DoneImpl()

Comment: For what part of the example above do you get an error? [Here's working source for the first option: http://ideone.com/8Iw6Hl .]