# How to call derived method from base

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

This question is possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17324078/398460), but I don't understand how the answer applies to my application. I have a base class with multiple derived classes. The class methods should all have the same name. The application receives UDP messages that need to be decoded differently based on the datagram type. For example, how can Decode in BaseDatagram be made to call Decode in DerivedDatagramA or DerivedDatagramB?

```
class DerivedDatagramA: public BaseDatagram
{
   ...
};

class DerivedDatagramB: public BaseDatagram
{
   ...
};

void BaseDatagram::Decode(uint8_t * buffer)
{
    switch(buffer[DATAGRAM_TYPE])
    {
        case DATAGRAM_TYPE_A:
            Decode(buffer); // How to call decode in DerivedDatagramA?
            break;
        case DATAGRAM_TYPE_B:
            Decode(buffer); // How to call decode in DerivedDatagramB?
            break;
```

Comment: You do not want inheritance here  (and you want it, in a different way). Make` BaseDatagram a dispatcher for datagrams (Than BaseDatagram is no Datagram anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `BaseDatagram::Decode(uint8_t*)` as virtual, and the call to `Decode()` will be dispatched to `DerivedDatagramA::Decode(uint8_t*)` or `DerivedDatagramB::Decode(uint8_t*)` automatically according to the object type.

Comment: While this makes sense in general, it's not obvious from the posted code that *any* objects of derived types are even ever created.

Comment: Yes. The derived objects are created.

Comment: I know how to declare a virtual method, but it is still not clear how the proper object is called. There is no difference in the signature. The `buffer[DATAGRAM_TYPE]` indicates how the datagram should be decoded. I could use different names but there are other common features in the base class (crc, ack id). Is there any issue using the approach mentioned in the comment by @DieterLücking?

Comment: @jacknad `Yes. The derived objects are created` If the `this` pointer on which you call `Decode` is of the correct derived type already, and if you make `Decode` virtual, than any calls to it will be automatically routed to the implementation in the derived class. The whole `switch` in `BaseDatagram::Decode` becomes unnecessary, and you can keep the function just for `/* oops: unknown datagram type */`. P.S. I see no issue with @DieterLücking's approach, assuming we both read it the same way.